# How to unpack multiple tuples in function call

Tags: python, tuples

If I have a function `def f(a, b, c, d)` and two tuples, each with two elements, is there any way to unpack these tuples so that I can send their values to the function?

```
f(*tup1, *tup2)
```

Comment: I also felt that this should work. Allowing only one * and ** expression to expand arguments in function _calls_ seems like an unnecessary restriction to me. Likewise to allow it only at the end of the list. This restriction leads in practice to tuple- and dict-building code clutter around function calls.

Comment: As of [Python 3.5.0](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/), thanks to [PEP-448](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), your psuedocode is now valid Python. See [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10564819/722121).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of [the release of Python 3.5.0](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-350/), [PEP 448 "Additional Unpacking Generalizations"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) makes the natural syntax for this valid Python:

```
>>> f(*tup1, *tup2)
1 2 2 3
```

In older versions of Python, you can need to concatenate the tuples together to provide a single expanded argument:

```
>>> tup1 = 1, 2
>>> tup2 = 2, 3
>>> def f(a, b, c, d):
        print(a, b, c, d)

>>> f(*tup1+tup2)
1 2 2 3
```

Comment: If tup1 is length 4, does tup2 get ignored? Is that the desired behaviour?

Comment: @Spacedman No, 6 values would get sent, and you would get an error (or it would work for a function that takes 6 arguments).

Comment: Right, but if the two tups add up to length four it will work but mighty mask a subtle bug. I'd always prefer to explicitly unpack.

Comment: I think this is closest to the psuedo-code that the asker submitted. He wanted a way to unpack all the values from two tuples, which is the behaviour my answer gives. While there are potential bugs, all the methods have them, and that's more a matter of design for the program.

Answer (score 11):

Another approach using `chain`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> def foo(a,b,c,d):
        print a,b,c,d


>>> tup1 = (1,2)
>>> tup2 = (3,4)
>>> foo(*chain(tup1,tup2))
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: @Lattyware correct, but for two tuples your solution is fastest according to my tests.