# Error when passing two parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I made a method to click on the calendar field and then choose the date, but when I move the parameters, is returning error.

**My method**

```
def select_current_date(self, *locator1, *locator2):

    self.driver.find_element(*locator1).click()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, AUTOCOMPLETE_TIMEOUT).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w")))
    self.driver.find_element(*locator2).click()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, AUTOCOMPLETE_TIMEOUT).until(
        EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-datepicker-title")))
```

**Passing the parameters**

```
self.select_current_date(*EventsLocators.RECEIVED, *EventsLocators.CURRENT_DATE)
```

**My error**

```
E     File "/Users/rafael/Desktop/projects/automated_tests/base.py", line 23
E       def select_current_date(self, *locator1, *locator2):
E                                                ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need (and actually you [cannot do it this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098105/unpacking-more-than-one-list-as-argument-for-a-function)) to unpack the arguments, replace:

```
def select_current_date(self, *locator1, *locator2):
```

with just:

```
def select_current_date(self, locator1, locator2):
```

When calling the method, now simply use:

```
self.select_current_date(EventsLocators.RECEIVED, EventsLocators.CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: @Rafael cause you need to remove the * when calling the method.

Comment: @Rafael and, looks like you might not need the * when actually using `locator1` and `locator2` inside the method.

Comment: Weird, because when I pass just one parameters, work fine. Example from another method that I use: `    def clear_sendkeys(self, value, *locator):
        self.driver.find_element(*locator).clear()
        self.driver.find_element(*locator).send_keys(value)` The problem is using two parameters

Comment: @Rafael could you please post what are the `EventsLocators.RECEIVED` and `EventsLocators.CURRENT_DATE` values? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but I'm getting the error `InvalidSelectorException: Message: Invalid locator values passed in` When selenium will interact in this field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130148/discussion-between-rafael-and-alecxe).

Answer (score 1):

If you [read the docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) for your method you'll see:

> `find_element(by='id', value=None)`

That means `find_element` needs two parameters. I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that `EventsLocators.RECEIVED` is a 2-element list or tuple. If it's not, then this won't work at all. But what you actually need to do is just remove the `*`s from your function definition and function call:

```
def select_current_date(self, locator1, locator2):

    self.driver.find_element(*locator1).click()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, AUTOCOMPLETE_TIMEOUT).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-w")))
    self.driver.find_element(*locator2).click()
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, AUTOCOMPLETE_TIMEOUT).until(
        EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ui-datepicker-title")))

thing_one = ['by', 'value']
thing_two = ['replace', 'these things']
self.select_current_date(thing_one, thing_two)
```

I don't know the particulars of what you're passing in, but they must be some kind of iterable, otherwise your function signatures won't match.

Answer (score -3):

Python doesn't have pointers so you don't need * there

Comment: That's not what `*` does in Python.

Comment: python use it for keyword(`**kwargs`) arguments and use when you dont know how many parameters(`*args`) your function will get. so this is wrong information

Comment: Actually every variable in Python is a pointer. All variables point to objects, hence, pointer.